# off-screen divs are not visible because webpage doesn't scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am creating the homepage of a website for a school assignment, but my webpage doesn't scroll so the offscreen divs are not visible. I have browsed this forum and the web studying the solutions proposed to other relevant questions, but they don't seem to work for me.
I put my code below (I have removed those parts which are not relevant)... please, can somebody tell me what is wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help.

```css
*{margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


.wrap {
    width: 59em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%
}

img.resize {
    width: 944px;
}


#header {
    background: url("...") 100% no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 14.37em;
    
}

#testo-header{
    background-color: white;
    height: 4.375em;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5em;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 4.375em;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-left: 8em;
}

#testo-header:before {
    content: '\0020';
    background-image: url(...);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height:5.625em;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 11.25em;
    z-index: -1;
}
ul#nav {
    background-color: white;
    height: 70px;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
    font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 35px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 5;
}

ul#nav li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    padding: 20px;

}


#main {
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    top:1em;
    
}

#title {
    height: 15em;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #888888;
    width: 944px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

ul#social {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
}
ul#social li {
    padding: 3px;
    float: left;
    
}

#content {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 120px;
}

#ingredienti {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>My site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind|Play" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="testo-header">
                <h1>Tomatoes</h1>
            </div>
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="selected">Ricette</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Categorie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
    <div id="main">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="title">
                <a href="#" class="selected">Starters</a>
                <ul id="social">
                    <li><img src="..." width="25" height="25"></li>
                    <li><img src="..." width="25" height="25"></li>
                    <li><img src="..." width="25" height="25"></li>
                </ul>
                <h2>salad</h2>
                <img class="resize" src="...">
                
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="ingredients">
                    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
                    
                </div>
                <div id="comments"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="aside">
            </div>
        </div>     
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="column">
                <h4>Informazioni</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h4>Categorie</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h4>Mangiare fuori</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="bottom">
                <h5>Newsletter</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a close div starting from where you opened the `<div id="header">`, add that and the scroll bar will appear